# jQuery UI autocomplete shows value instead of label in the input field

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

A potentially simple issue with jQuery UI autocomplete is stumping me. My source is

```
var ac = [
    {
        label: "One Thing",
        value: "One-Thing"
    },
    {
        label: "Two Thing",
        value: "Two-Thing"
    },      
]
```

I am invoking the widget with

```
$(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: PK.getAutocompleteSource(),
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;  
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            PK.render(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

All works fine. When I type in the `#search` input field, the matching label shows up in the dropdown, and when I `select` the correct search is performed. The widget even shows the `label` in the `#search` input field as I select different items in the dropdown using the arrow keys (or the mouse). Except, soon as I hit enter, the widget fills the `#search` input field with the `value` instead of the `label`. So the field shows **One-Thing** instead of **One Thing**.

How can I correct this? Surely what I am expecting is the more reasonable behavior, no?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

if you want the label to be your value, just have the source be

```
var ac = ["One Thing", "Two Thing"]
```

alternatively, the `select` method of autocompletes default action is to put the `value` object (if specified) as the value of your input.  you could also put `event.preventDefault()` in the select function and it will put the label as the value (as you have)

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
        PK.render(ui.item.value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, `event.preventDefault();` did the trick. Seriously, this should be in the docs.

Comment: @dpp the `focus` callback (in the original question) returned false, which is another way of skipping the default behavior when using the arrow keys of using the `value` and not the `label`.  once an item is selected from the list, regardless of how, it calls the `select` callback and there is where you want to either use `preventDefault()` or `return false` to skip the default behavior

Comment: got same problem, it display the value instead of label.  preventDefault() work!!!

Answer (score 20):

If you want your label to be your value in the text box onFocus AND onSelect use this code:

```
select: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#hiddenid').val(ui.item.value); 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label); },

focus: function(event, ui) { 
       event.preventDefault(); 
       $("#search").val(ui.item.label);}
```

I was missing the onFocus event (only setting the onSelect event). Thus, the value continued to show in the text input.

Comment: This didn't work for me because I am also using `autofocus:true`.  The problem is type ahead searching triggers `focus` event on each keystroke, and the user's typing is aborted every keystroke and replaced with current highlighted item `$("#search").val(ui.item.label);`.

Answer (score 6):

I was still haveing a problem with arrow keys showing the values. So I actually found it better to assign both the value and label to the label, and then put the value on a 3rd property of the data. For example let's put it on id.

```
var ac = [
    {
        label: "One Thing",
        value: "One Thing",
        id: "One-Thing",
    },
    {
        label: "Two Thing",
        value: "Two Thing",
        id: "Two-Thing"
    },      
]
```

Then when you use the select event, you can get id from ui:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    PK.render(ui.item.id);
}
```