# Get only first term from JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, autocomplete

**Problem:**

My JQuery autocomplete is returning two keywords that is found in the database. I want the user to see both when searching but when choosing an option only one keyword should be selected and inserted as the value.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>Country:</label>
            <input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'>
        </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            //autocomplete
            $(".auto").autocomplete({
                source: "search.php",
                minLength: 1
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        $return_arr = array();

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM airports WHERE name LIKE :term OR iata LIKE :term');
            $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $return_arr[] =  $row['iata'] . ' (' . $row['name'] . ')';
            }

        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        echo json_encode($return_arr);
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

As you can see, the entire name shows in the input field. But I only want the abbreviation to be there instead. The question is thus:

How do you allow the user to see the full name while searching but only choose the abbreviation once the user makes the choice?

[image]

**Desired output:**

To only get the abbreviation of the airport in the input field (for instance JFK).

Comment: did you check this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440428/jquery-catching-click-event-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: I guess `$return_arr[] =  array('id' => $row['iata'], 'value' => $row['iata'], 'text' => $row['iata'] . ' (' . $row['name'] . ')');` should do the trick

Comment: @Bob0t It does not, the abbreviation shows up only and not the full name of the airport. Try searching for JFK at the demo: https://abc-supervisor.c9users.io/t.php

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found here: [jQuery UI autocomplete shows value instead of label in the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375720/jquery-ui-autocomplete-shows-value-instead-of-label-in-the-input-field)

```
$return_arr[] = array('value' => $row['iata'], 'label' => $row['iata'] . ' (' . $row['name'] . ')');
```

jQuery use the combination `label`and `value`, which was the solution.